# google maps API info window style error

Tags: c#, google-maps

im using google maps api and im having this problem with showing the info window

(see image)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLUNH.png

im not using any custom designs just the google default

im not getting a close icon or the bottom style to link to marker

Comment: A link to live code would be very valuable.

Comment: its only internal at the moment it seems like the way the api is loading the images and building the box cannot position the background image correctly

Comment: You can use JS Fiddle to load it to a temporary space for folks to view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem occurred while setting the "max-width:100%" for an img tag.
Solved with this css code:

```
#map img { max-width:none !important; }
```

Firdor